# High Tech Audience

Tags: technical-writing, audience

I have to write a simple introduction on the topic **HTTP** and its audience will be high tech.

I am having a bit of problem in how to describe it in high tech audience?
Can any one would suggest me how to complete the task?
Thanks

Comment: Why write another introduction to HTTP at all when so many are already available on the Web? Why would any of the many available introductions not work for your target audience? If they would not work, then the reason that they would not work will inform how you describe it uniquely for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audience can be broad. You may have some folks who are new, they may need that explanation (just a gist) to remind them that concept (yes, even http!).

So you can have a stand alone standard definition, and right after that a funny analogy or humorous view at it. This would make the "high tech folk" appreciate a humorous way to look at something they feel is very basic. And also you don't risk missing out on the "newer" audience.

Never assume an audience as a single entity. There is almost always a knowledge spread amongst them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like "high tech" is the ideal audience. You don't have to dumb it down or use analogies. Your explanation can be, like, two sentences. Look up the definition in a few places and rewrite it in your own words.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as any writing project: tell a story.

In technical writing, it is not only just as important to tell a story, it might be even more important than in other disciplines. The material can be dry or very conceptually mysterious.

You might be tempted to read an HTTP spec and just crib dryly from that. But if you think about it, HTTP is what literally links the entire WorldWideWeb together. It’s actually one of the more romantic technologies in the world. Tell us how and why it came to be, who created it, who uses it and how, what it does and how it does it, and what it has enabled us to do.